# Error when starting Cassandra server on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, cassandra

I've downloaded all the files of Cassandra and put them in `C:\cassandra` folder. I've checked that JAVA_HOME and CASSANDRA_HOME Environment variables are set correctly (`echo %CASSANDRA_HOME% -> C:\cassandra`)

I've modified the config file, for example:

```
commitlog_directory: C:/cassandra/storage/commitlog
```

I've tried with both back slash and forward slash for the directory separator. I went to cassandra 'BIN' directory and ran `cassandra -f`.

I get an error:

```
Starting Cassandra Server

The system cannot find the path specified
```

This is where I am stuck and don't know how to proceed. I get the same error when running `cassandra-cli` too. I don't want to use Datastax, as I am experimenting with the 1.2 beta right now.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I ran into this same error, caused by cmd.exe not finding a file referenced in the batch script.  In my case, the cause was an improperly-set `JAVA_HOME` variable.  I had set the value to `c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin`, but it should be `c:\Program Files\Java\jre6` so that it doesn't break this section of `cassandra.bat`:

```
:runDaemon
echo Starting Cassandra Server
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" %JAVA_OPTS% %CASSANDRA_PARAMS% -cp %CASSANDRA_CLASSPATH% "%CASSANDRA_MAIN%"
goto finally
```

Also, I found [this guide](http://support.qualityunit.com/249500-Cassandra-installation-on-Windows-7) helpful when setting up Cassandra 1.2.5 on Windows 7.  The configuration file it references is now located at `conf/cassandra.yaml`, but the same steps apply.

Comment: Thanks, If you install the msi package, jre is installed with cassandra so you should point JAVA_HOME to something like: C:\Program Files\DataStax Community\jre

Answer (score 1):

From memory, on Windows you may need to run `cassandra.bat -f` not `cassandra -f` (which would be the equivalent Linux bash script) - check them in a text editor to be sure...

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this same error. Resolved it.

**Open cmd as an administrator by selecting "run as an administrator" option.**

And then give the path to Cassandra and run it. For instance : C:\Program Files\cassandra